# Firebase and Objective C: use of undeclared identifier 'Firebase'

Tags: objective-c, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, offline

I am using latest version of Firebase, installed via pod. But when trying to include offline capabilities, with the above instruction, I get error message "use of undeclared identifier 'Firebase'". I have: `@import Firebase`, but also played around with several `#import <Firebase.h>` .... all without success to avoid the error message.

I don't understand, as this is taken directly from the Firebase documentation. Or is the documentation not up-to-date?

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE: Sorry was my mistake. I got link to the Firebase SDK 2.5.1. Looking at the correct and latest documentation, I have found that the instruction should now be:

```
[FIRDatabase database].persistenceEnabled = YES;
```

That doesn't produce any error.